# Step through 2D array in hexagon pattern

Tags: c#, for-loop, math, unity-game-engine

I use a nested for loop to create a grid of hexagons. This creates a square grid:

```
for (int z = 0; z < gridSize; z++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < gridSize; x++)
    {
            // creates verts for a hexagon shape which later form a mesh
            // x and z form the basis of the Vector3 position of the center 
            // of each hexagon
            CreateCell(x, z); 
    }
}
```

[image]

I've drawn the start and end values for z & x on the image.

What I'd like is to have the grid itself also shaped hexagonally:

[image]

I think figured out the limits for x:

```
int greaterThan = Mathf.RoundToInt(gridSize/ 3) - 1;
int lessThan = width - greaterThan;
```

And that (I think) x should only be at it's min and max (0 & 6 in the examples) when z = gridSize / 2 rounded up, though I may well be wrong!

I tried putting a bunch if IFs in the loops but it quickly started to get overly complicated, I figure there must be a more 'mathsy' way to do it, but sadly I'm not mathsy!

Any idea how I can write a loop to form the required pattern?

Answer (score 2):

If @AsfK's solution is not good enough, I'll give it a try as well:

```
    private static void PrintHexLine(int z, int size)
    {
        if (z >= size)
        {
            z = 2 * size - 2 - z;
        }
        int start = size - z - 1;
        int end = start + size + z;
        for (int x = 0; x < start; x++)
        {
            Console.Write(" ");
        }
        for (int x = start; x < end; x++)
        {
            Console.Write("* ");
            //Console.Write((x - start / 2) + " "); // position v1
            //Console.Write((x - (start + 1) / 2) + " "); // position v2

        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    public static void PrintHex(int size)
    {
        for (int z = 0; z < 2 * size - 1; z++)
        {
            PrintHexLine(z, size);
        }
    }
```

With such code `PrintHex(4)` results in

```
   * * * *
  * * * * *
 * * * * * *
* * * * * * *
 * * * * * *
  * * * * *
   * * * *
```

And if you uncomment the `position v1` line instead of the one that prints `"* "`, you'll get

```
   2 3 4 5
  1 2 3 4 5
 1 2 3 4 5 6
0 1 2 3 4 5 6
 1 2 3 4 5 6
  1 2 3 4 5
   2 3 4 5
```

similarly `position v2`

```
   1 2 3 4
  1 2 3 4 5
 0 1 2 3 4 5
0 1 2 3 4 5 6
 0 1 2 3 4 5
  1 2 3 4 5
   1 2 3 4
```

which looks like the `x` indices you want.  Basing on your data I'm not really sure whether you need `v1` or `v2` variant. The `v2` looks more consistent to me but it really depends on how your `CreateCell(x, z);` treats the `x = 0` case.

P.S. obviously you can inline `PrintHexLine` call but it means having two different `z` variables that you should not mess up with and I think it is cleaner to move that in a separate method.

Answer (score 1):

According your excepted picture the center is the long row (gridSize = 7).

`floor(7/2) = 3` (/2 because the long row is in the center)

Now, `gridSize - 3 = 4`  ==> 4 items in your first row

Then each iterate add one till you have 7 items in one row.

Then do a minus...

it's the code (draw "*", not added spaces before and after..)

```
int gridSize = 7;
int center = 7/2;
int delta = 1;
for (int r = 0; r < gridSize; r++) {
    for (int c = gridSize - center; c < gridSize + delta; c++){
        System.out.print("*");
        // location of c = c - delta (position)
    }
    System.out.println();
    if (r < center)
        delta++;
    else
        delta--;
}
```

Comment: If you use a circle algorithm using sin(x) and cos(x) each point along the circumference of a hexagon is 60 degrees apart. The center of the hexagon below and to the left is 210 degrees, and the one to the bottom right is at 150 degrees.

Comment: @EddingtonsMonkey, looks really cool, but it's not my strongest :) will be glad to see your full answer!

Comment: @AsfK - Your code produced some really odd results so I can't accept as an answer but it did nudge me in the right direction, keeping track of the row size and incrementing or subtracting before / after the mid point. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to a hint from AsfK I solved it like this

```
int xL, xU, xMid, zM2;
xL = Mathf.FloorToInt(width / 3) - 1;
xU = (width - xL) + 1;
xMid = Mathf.FloorToInt(width / 2);

for (int z = 0; z < height; z++)
{
    for (int x = xL; x < xU; x++)
    {
        CreateCell(x, z);
    }

    zM2 = z % 2;

    if(z < xMid)
    {
        if (zM2 == 0)
        {
            xL--;
        }
        if (z > 0 && zM2 == 1)
        {
            xU++;
        }
    } else
    {
        if (zM2 == 1)
        {
            xL++;
        }
        if (zM2 == 0)
        {
            xU--;
        }
        if (z == width - 1)
        {
            xL--;
            xU++;
        }
    }
}
```

Would be great if anyone can think of a more elegant solution!

Comment: Absinthe, take a look at my solution and let me know if this is not what you need. Maybe I'll be able to fix it.